# How to clear validation errors after providing a file download on form submit?

Tags: validation, jsf, download

I've got a page where there is an input field and a button. Clicking the button generates a PDF report, based on the value entered in the input field. My problem lies in the fact that the input field needs some special formatting, and I have a validator that will fire if the required format is not present.

Suppose I enter an invalid value in the field, then click the button. The PDF report won't be generated because of the validation, and the field becomes red, as expected. But then I enter a correct value (with the field still red) and press the button. The report gets generated but the field remains red. That's because I've used FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete() after the PDF generation so the normal Faces lifecycle has been bypassed and the clearing of the validation errors does not trigger anymore for this request.

How can I generate the PDF report but still force Faces to determine that the validation error should be cleared? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done in one HTTP response. You'd need to let the client send two requests so that you can return two responses; one to clear the errors and other to return the PDF. You'd only need to do some rework in the bean's action method and probably add a file serving servlet.

Basically, you need to store the PDF in local (temp) disk location or maybe in memory and let JSF conditionally render some JavaScript which in turn downloads the PDF. The PDF can be downloaded through a servlet or some additional webapp context pointing to the local disk location.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="Download" action="#{bean.submit}" />
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty bean.pdfURL}">
        <script>window.location = '#{bean.pdfURL}';</script>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

with

```
public void submit() {
    // Create PDF and store as byte[] in memory, or as File on disk.
    // Then create an unique URL to the PDF.
    pdfURL = externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/pdf/" + pdfID;
}
```

which should generate the following on a succesful form submit (which should also clear the validation errors!)

```
<script>window.location = '/contextname/pdf/uniquefilename.pdf';</script>
```

If you've registered `/some/path/to/pdf` as another webapp context in the server configuration, then you can just store the `File` in there and it will be downloaded. But if you can't because you have no control over the server configuration, then you'd need to create a servlet which is mapped on an URL pattern of `/pdf/*` and does something like the following in `doGet()` method:

```
String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
File pdf = new File("/some/path/to/pdf", filename);

response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));

InputStream input = new FileInputStream(pdf);
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
// Now just write input to output.
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I thought that maybe it was possible to do it in a single request with some JSF  trick. I will definitely give your idea a try tomorrow, thank you.